# How do I display specific sections of multiple web pages on a web page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have some web pages that I just need to have the graph displayed inside. How do I show them all in one page with Iframe?

Comment: Normally you don't, the other server controls the page contents .  You could try writing script pages that fetch the other site's page, scrape and parse it, then display that cut down version.  If you do that don't be surprised if your server ends up blocked by the other site's firewall.

Comment: All pages are in my own domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can't load part of a page with an iframe. You could load a specific section of the page with jQuery, a JavaScript library.

Example:

`jQuery('#where-you-want-to-load-the-content').load('http://www.example.com/your-page.php #section-you-want-to-bring-in');`

To explain: the `#where-you-want-to-load-the-content` is representative of some ID on the page, like `<div id="where-you-want-to-load-the-content"></div>` and `#section-you-want-to-bring-in` is the HTML wrapper of the section of the page you're bringing in.

Example:

`<div id="section-you-want-to-bring-in">Hello!</div>` will be brought into your code section `<div id="where-you-want-to-load-the-content"></div>`